# Exchange 2007 to exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, exchange-2010, exchange-migration

I have performed the upgrade from 03 to 07.
Is the upgrade from 07 to 10 similar or am I in for surprises?

I have training with exchange 07, but not exchange 2010. So I'm trying to determine if I should get training for a 07 to 10 migration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration from Exchange 2007 to Exchange 2010 is pretty painless. Exchange 2010 was, from an administrator's perspective, a minor refresh on Exchange 2007. It's not at all like the major changes between, say, Exchange 5.5 to 2000 or 2003 to 2007.

Spin up a simple lab on some virtual machines and play around with the migration. That's your best bet to determine whether you need addt'l training. My guess is that if you're comfortable w/ Exchange 2007 you'll have no problem dealing with migrating to Exchange 2010.